# What is windows form c# writeline equivalent

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have created an order form that includes a 16 length string array. Depending on the customer selection, I need the info from the array to appear in a text box e.g order summary. I can't figure it out. Here is sample code from one radio button and one check box. If these were selected how do I get the selection to display in a box? Please note I already have the "cost" part of it working correctly.

```
//Handle CPU Box Radio Btn
if (rdInteli3.Checked)
{
     cost += 100.00;
     item [0] = "Intel i3";
}

//Handle Hard Drive Check Box
if (ckHardDrive1Tb.Checked)
{
      cost += 200.00;
      item[11] = "1 TB Hard Drive";
}
```

I've tried this. Didn't work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
     txtSummary.Text = item[i];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have a multi-line `TextBox` control. You can append text to the control by calling its [`AppendText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx) method. You code would look like this:

```
txtSummary.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    txtSummary.AppendText(item[i]);
}
```

You may wish to include new lines each time you add an item. In that case change the code like so:

```
txtSummary.AppendText(item[i]);
txtSummary.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
```

or perhaps:

```
txtSummary.AppendText(item[i] + Environment.NewLine);
```

An alternative form is to use concatenation on the `Text` property:

```
txtSummary.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    txtSummary.Text += item[i] + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

And yet another option would be to build the text outside the control, for instance using a `StringBuilder` instance, and then assigning it all to the `Text` property in one go.

Comment: `txtSummary.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    txtSummary.Text += item[i] + Environment.NewLine;
}`

Comment: Worked for what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you want to use [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx):

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
```

Comment: Well, the question asks for the text to appear in a text box

Comment: @DavidHeffernan simply and precisely ;)

Answer (score 2):

> What is windows form c# writeline equivalent

Its the same `Console.WriteLine` but since there is no console you will see the output in [`Output`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3hk6fby3.aspx) window.

> I need the info from the array to appear in a text box

You need to build a string , better if you use `StringBuilder`. Append your data there and then assign the result to your `TextBox.Text` property.

If your data is in array `item` then , **its better if you use string.Join** like:

```
txtSummary.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, item);
```

If you want to use `StringBuilder` then you can do:

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
   {
      sb.Append(item[i]);
   }

```
txtSummary.Text = sb.ToString();
```

> Using string builder, how do I had space between the selection and
>   maybe a comma?

You can do:

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
   {
      sb.Append(item[i]);
      sb.Append(" ,");
   }

    txtSummary.Text = sb.ToString().Trim(',',' ');
```

Or **better**

```
txtSummary.Text = string.Join(" ,", item);
```

Comment: Using string builder, how do I had space between the selections and maybe a comma?

Comment: @user1951143, just edited the answer for your comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder or String.Format to build a complete string that you want to show to the user. String.Format uses similar semantics as WriteLine.

Then assign this string to a MessageBox, a label or a textfield on your form or whereever you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Debud.WriteLine("This is test string");
```

You can check the result at the [Output Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3hk6fby3.aspx)